# Using jQuery to find an image by its source

Tags: jquery, image, find

I am trying to find an image within the DOM based on its filename or src...

I understand using

```
$("img[src$='myimage.jpg']")
```

should work but
what if you are greabbing the filename on the fly with jquery like so:

```
$(".slides_container img").click(function() {
 var photo = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

How do I put the `photo` var in there?

I tried this with no luck:

```
$("img[src$='" + photo + "']");
```

Comment: Hang on, you're trying to find an `mg` element whose `src` ends with its own `src` attribute?

Comment: @david I think he's trying to find all images whose src ends with the same src as the image that was clicked.  There may be more than one.

Comment: Possibly, but I'd prefer to have a *clearly-stated intent*, rather than just a non-working piece of code with *no* explanation of what's *required* of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
  var item=$("img[src='" + photo + "']");
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Nd8aM/9/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the source of all images to the source of the clicked image, you can use jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method like this.

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var photo = $(this).attr('src');
    $("img").filter(function(index) {
        $(this).css('border-color','transparent');
                      return $(this).attr('src').match(photo);
                }).css('border-color','#f0f');
});​
```

​
[Here's my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/6ha9z/).

The `match` takes regex so you can do almost anything with it. I don't see why

```
$("img[src$='" + photo + "']");
```

didn't work out for you, the string building is legit, the `'` quotes aren't necessary though.

To replicate `$=` with regex use `/string$/` where `string` is the query to match.